# How to apply multiple whereclause in sqlalchmey in dask while fetching large dataset from teradata

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, dask, teradatasql

I am trying to fetch larger dataset from teradata using dask and sqlalchmey. I am able to apply single whereclause and able to fetch data.below is the working code

```
td_engine = create_engine(connString)
metadata = MetaData()
t = Table(
    "table",
    metadata,
    Column("c1"),
    schema="schema",
  )
sql = select([t]).where(
        t.c.c1 == 'abc',
    )
)
start = perf_counter()
df = dd.read_sql_table(sql, connString, index_col="c1",schema="schema")
end = perf_counter()
print("Time taken to execute the code {}".format(end - start))
print(df.head())
```

but when I am trying to apply and in whereclause I am getting error

```
sql = select([t]).where(
and_(
        t.c.c1 == 'abc',
        t.c.c2 == 'xyz'
    )
)
```

Comment: Please show your exception. It may be tricky, but it would be very useful to would-be answerers if you could create a DB (sqlite) with a similar structure to your own data.

Answer (score -1):

More context would be helpful. If you simply need to execute the query, have you considered using the pandas read_sql function and composing the SQL request yourself?

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd
with teradatasql.connect(host="whomooz",user="guest",password="please") as con:
  df = pd.read_sql("select c1 from mytable where c1='abc' and c2='xyz'", con)
  print(df.head())
```

Or is there a specific need to use the pandas functions to construct the SQL request?

Comment: The OP asked about dask, which has restrictions for loading from SQL.